# MySQL Calculate minimum price of a service with varying starting time

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table like this:

**Prices**

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| service_id | starting_time | ending_time | price_per_hour |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 08:00:00      | 10:00:00    | 90             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 10:00:00      | 11:00:00    | 50             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 11:00:00      | 15:00:00    | 80             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now a user of my web page wants to find service providers with lowest price. They tell me starting time of the service, duration and (here's the tricky part) tolerance for the starting time. Say, service should start at 10am, should last 2 hours but they are willing to come one hour earlier or later (+/- 1 hour to starting time).

I cannot seem to come up with an idea of one query to get me the lowest possible price, depending if the service starts at 9am, 10am or 11am. starting time tolerance may vary. It's easy, if there's no tolerance, you just select all rows from prices that apply to the service time, calculate their share in price and then sum the subquery. But how do I introduce the variable starting time factor into that?

This is a simplified query to calculate price knowing exact starting point of the service. `:service_start` and `service_end` are placeholders.

```
SELECT SUM(t1.price) FROM

    (SELECT price_per_hour * TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( IF(ending_time < :service_end,
     ending_time, :service_end), IF(starting_time < :service_start, :service_start,
     starting_time) ) ) / 3600 AS price FROM prices WHERE service_id = 1 AND NOT
     (starting_time >= :service_end OR ending_time <= :service_start)) AS t1
```

And now I have no idea where to go on from here. How to introduce variability of service starting time.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I think I was too lazy to think deeper about that before. I believe it can't be done using MySQL. I've broken it down to mathematical equasions that would solve it and I believe it's not something you can implement in MySQL (two equasions with many variables). I think it's going to have to be some brute force calculations on PHP side to get what I want.

In this instance I would want to minimise x * 90 + y * 50 + z * 80, where x, y, z is number of hours taken from each price range given some conditions, such as x,y,z%0,5 = 0 (half an hour step), x+y+z = 2, etc.

**EDIT 2:**

I'll describe the issue in more detail, as it seems I wansn't specific enough:

I have three tables that are relevant to this issue:

**services**

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| service_id | service_type_id | provider_id | name | starting_time       | ending_time         |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2          | 1               | 3                  | 2014-02-07 08:00:00 | 2014-02-07 23:00:00 |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**prices** (more a price list)

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| service_type_id | provider_id | starting_time | ending_time | price_per_hour |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1               | 3           | 08:00:00      | 10:00:00    | 90             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1               | 3           | 10:00:00      | 11:00:00    | 50             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1               | 3           | 11:00:00      | 15:00:00    | 80             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1               | 3           | 15:00:00      | 23:00:00    | 70             |
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**service_slots**

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| service_slot_id | service_id | starting_time       | ending_time         | booked |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1               | 2          | 2014-02-07 08:00:00 | 2014-02-07 09:00:00 | 1      |
| 2               | 2          | 2014-02-07 09:00:00 | 2014-02-07 17:00:00 | 0      |
| 3               | 2          | 2014-02-07 17:00:00 | 2014-02-07 19:00:00 | 1      |
| 4               | 2          | 2014-02-07 19:00:00 | 2014-02-07 21:00:00 | 1      |
| 5               | 2          | 2014-02-07 21:00:00 | 2014-02-07 23:00:00 | 0      |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first table contains service schedule of a provider. The provider says they're offering the service between 8am and 11pm. You can book as much time off that service as you want (think tennis court booking).

They also have a pricing for those services. This pricing says that every day (during price list validity), the service costs this and that between this and that hour. You can book the service across price ranges. That is, if the price list says that the service costs 90 between 8am and 10am and 50 between 10am and 11am, it's perfectly fine for you to book between 9 and 11. Then two price ranges apply to your booking.

The third table holds information on which chunk (slot) of a particular service has been booked.

What I do is first query service_slots for available chunks then I need to get the price for the entire duration of the chunk, knowing that price may change in the middle of the chunk's duration.

I hope I mad myself more clear this time :)

Comment: Why does your query use `sum()` if you want the minimum price?

Comment: Because that's a query to get the full price of the service knowing exactly the starting time. Now what I don't know is how to turn it so that it calculates minimum price, depending on starting time (9 - 11 am, for exammple) in one query.

Answer (score 1):

**HEAVILY EDITED, SO OLD POST IS GONE!**

First, check out my codes.

My test table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price(
    id              INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    pid             INT(20) NOT NULL,
    staring_time    DATETIME,
    ending_time     DATETIME,
    price           INT(20) NOT NULL
);
```

And the queries:

```
SET @start_pref = '2014-02-07 02:00:00';
SET @end_pref   = '2014-02-07 04:00:00';

SELECT
    *,
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM price
        WHERE
            pid = p.pid AND
            starting_time <= @start_pref AND
            ending_time > @start_pref
    ) AS id_first,
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM price
        WHERE
            pid = p.pid AND
            ending_time >= @end_pref AND
            starting_time < @end_pref
    ) AS id_last,
    (
        SELECT IF(
            id_first = id_last,
            (
                SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_pref, @start_pref)*price)
                FROM price
                WHERE id = id_first AND pid = p.pid
            ),
            (
                (
                    SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(ending_time, @start_pref)*price)
                    FROM price
                    WHERE id = id_first AND pid = p.pid
                ) + (
                    SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(@end_pref, starting_time)*price)
                    FROM price
                    WHERE id = id_last AND pid = p.pid
                )
            )
        ) FROM price WHERE pid = p.pid AND id = id_first
    ) AS total
FROM price p
WHERE
    starting_time <= @start_pref AND @start_pref < ending_time
ORDER BY total ASC;
```

This only works for, when @start_pref and @end_pref covers 1 - 2 successive time-sched.

However, it does not work for, when the pref time covers more than 2 records.

Example:

```
Starting pref time: 1am
Ending pref time: 5am

For one specific provider
    1am - 2am - $10
    2am - 3am - $20
    4am - 5am - $30
```

This is because I didn't think of it beforehand when I started and finished my query.

Now if it is two or more, you'd need more subquery to find those id then add them on my `SELECT IF(` subquery.

Also, notice how I have/added the column `id`? So that I can tell easily if that `id` belongs to the same `pid` on the current query.

PID is Provider ID.

The whole [sql script.](http://pastebin.com/BePgGmQD)

Comment: I don't see how it's going to help me. I've changed my sample pricing table, for better clarity. The thing is, should the service start at 9, its total cost would be 140, should it start at 10, it would be 130, and 160 if it started at 11. And I want to extract minimum of that in a single query, not knowing the parameters in advance (such as service starting time, starting time spread, and service duration).

Comment: I reread your post. I was confused at first and hopefully I understand your requirements now. Please check out my new answer and hopefully it'd help you in anyway.

Comment: I believe I might have simplified my description too much. I did it for clarity, but I think that it was at the expense of clarity in the end :). I'll update my question in a minute to describe the situation in full.

Comment: hope now i at least helped you in anyway or answered your problem. at least vote it for effort :P

Comment: I figured as much that it cannot be done with a single, universal query. +1 for you though ;)